# Cisco router as IDS

Tags: router, firewall

Can a Cisco router act as an IDS for LAN traffic that does not pass through it? Specifically, can traffic passing through a switch be port mirrored to an interface on the router with the router acting as an IDS?

I am looking for a way to use an ISR G2 router like Snort to monitor traffic between devices on a LAN.

Comment: what model/ feature set do you have? regardless i don't think there is anything that will work exactly like you think that it may work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am looking for a way to use an ISR G2 router like Snort [snip]

Your entire question starts and stops right there. The IPS/IDS within IOS is not designed for out-of-band traffic inspection.  The router *must* be *inline* to inspect it.

Put simply, IOS is not SNORT. If you want SNORT, run SNORT.

(Also, the IPS/IDS within IOS is very slow -- being done entirely in the way under powered router CPU -- and often incomplete. You'll need a support contract to keep it remotely up to date.)

Answer (score 3):

No,

But what you CAN do is set up a box with SNORT.

Or you can apply an access-list to your Span session port that is just "permit ip any any log" and that will log traffic source and destination addresses (along with TCP/UDP port info). Then if you can redirect these log messages to a syslog server you could export them in realtime to a CSV and have an application like SNORT alalyze the traffic flows. Or you can log them locally on the device and then extract/parse them manually to look for anomalous traffic flows.

Answer (score -1):

I think John Kennedy is right, there isn't anything out there that seems like it fits the bill on your questions; but I'll give a wag at it anyhow.

> Can a Cisco router act as an IDS for LAN traffic that does not pass
>   through it?

No, although there are certain Cisco devices that can act as an IDS/IPS. Cisco has an [entire line](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps5729/Products_Sub_Category_Home.html) of products specializing in this, specifically.

These will likely be massive overkill for your situation though.

> Specifically, can traffic passing through a switch be port mirrored to
>   an interface on the router with the router acting as an IDS?

This has always been possible with port-mirroring ([SPAN ports](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/datacenter/sw/5_x/nx-os/system_management/configuration/guide/sm_14span.html)). They functionally do exactly what you're looking for. They replicate traffic ingressing/egressing an interface/VLAN and spit it out on a pre-defined port/VLAN.

> I am looking for a way to use an ISR G2 router like Snort to monitor
>   traffic between devices on a LAN.

I'm not so sure this model supports custom code (like snort) in the way you're expecting it to.

Although not as elegant, you could always set up a standalone machine to run your IDS applications on.

Comment: Cisco IOS routers cannot inspect traffic not passing through them - PERIOD. (Cisco IDS appliances are *not routers*) Again, the ability to "span" traffic isn't the question; an IOS *router* cannot inspect traffic that did not pass through it.

Comment: @RickyBeam You are correct, IOS cannot inspect traffic and the models listed won't act as a routing device. However, how is SPAN'ing not part of the question? He is asking about port-mirroring (i.e. Cisco SPAN technology)?

Comment: short version: "can I SPAN traffic into the router *acting as an IDS*" Answer: still no. (the span isn't the question)  Traffic must naturally flow through the router for the IOS IDS engine to work.